# Video Signature extraction in matlab

Tags: matlab, video, feature-extraction

I am developing an application for Visual duplicate detection. For that First i have extract Frames from video. Then i have calculate KeyFrame which has Highest RMS error. Now i have to calculate Features of different subregion of frames which are configured at various scales, 
shapes and locations. Then I have to apply ternary quantization of it to calculate Frame signature.

I am trying to calculate features but i cant getting it as per requirement. Can anyone please help to implement this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.